# Joining 2 parts of a movie together gives no video during the second part

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to encode a series of movies in my collection where each one is on two disks. I have come up with a rudimentary script that works with the first one just fine. However, for the second and third movies, for some reason, the final output file has issues where the video stream seems to be missing from the second half of the full movie. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ffmpeg -y -i video1.mkv  -c:v libx264 -pass 1  -preset slower -b:v 10000k -x264opts frameref=8:fast_pskip=0 -f rawvideo temp_1.mkv

ffmpeg -i temp_1.mkv -i audio1.dts -c:a dts -b:a 1500k -ar 48000 -c:v libx264 -pass 2 -preset slow -b:v 10000k -strict -2 -x264opts fram
eref=10:fast_pskip=0 part1_final.mkv

ffmpeg -y -i video2.mkv  -c:v libx264 -pass 1  -preset slower -b:v 10000k -x264opts frameref=8:fast_pskip=0 -f rawvideo temp_2.mkv

ffmpeg -i temp_2.mkv -i audio2.dts -c:a dts -b:a 1500k -ar 48000 -c:v libx264 -pass 2 -preset slow -b:v 10000k -strict -2 -x264opts fram
eref=10:fast_pskip=0 part2_final.mkv

ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 01:46:39 -i part1_final.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy  part1_trimmed.mkv

ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy FINAL.mkv
```

video1.mkv and video2.mkv are ripped from Blu-ray and processed through eac3to to be only the video track. Audio1.dts and audio2.dts are likewise just the respective audio tracks. I am having to trim the first disk finalized because there is about 6 seconds of black screen that I just don't want in the final video. Here is my input.txt:

```
file './part1_trimmed.mkv'
file './part2_final.mkv'
```

Here are the results of the ffprobe from part1_trimmed.mkv, part2_final.mkv, and FINAL.mkv:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'part1_trimmed.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.16.101
  Duration: 01:46:39.27, start: 0.083000, bitrate: 11543 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc56.16.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc56.16.100 dca

Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'part2_final.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.16.101
  Duration: 02:08:52.02, start: 0.083000, bitrate: 11545 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc56.16.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc56.16.100 dca

Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'FINAL.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.16.101
  Duration: 03:55:31.29, start: 0.083000, bitrate: 11544 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
```

Lastly, if it will help, here is what the video looks like during the second part of the FINAL.mkv:

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but if you use 2 pass encoding then the inputs to both passes must be the same video- say `video1.mkv` in your case. The output of the first pass can be to a null device because it is only meant to be a motion estimation pass. So `-f rawvideo /dev/null`. But I'm not even sure you are intending to do 2 pass.

Comment: Am i right to assume you want to join video1.mkv and video2.mkv, chopping off a last 6 seconds of video1.mkv?

Comment: I think I finally get how to do the 2-pass encoding correctly, you said it in a way that made it click for me, thanks. It doesn't actually use the output video that the first pass creates, just the temp files created.

As for the other part, yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do. After the encoding, I want to trim the end of the first part and join the 2 videos.

Comment: So I modified my run script and still got the same result. Any thoughts?

New script is here: http://pastebin.com/uNfRWj39

Comment: The link does not work for me. You may put up your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to join 2 films with a "chopping off" from one film, is to use the `trim` and `concatenate` filters in a chain. First set up to trim the film to be chopped and then make the trimmed version available to the concatenate filter to join.

Essentially `Film1 -> trim -> trimmed_version; [trimmed_version] + [film2] -> concatenate -> output`.
With **audio** and **video** the 2 streams require their own chains. So for trimming `film1.mkv` and joining to `film2.mkv` in a 2 pass format, this would be the scheme:

```
ffmpeg -i film1.mkv -i film2.mkv -y -filter_complex '[0:a]atrim=duration=6399, asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[at]; [0:v] trim=duration=6399, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vt]; [vt] [at] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v] [a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' -pass 1 [other_encoding_parameters] -f mp4 /dev/null

ffmpeg -i film1.mov -i film2.mov -y -filter_complex '[0:a]atrim=duration=6399, asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[at]; [0:v] trim=duration=6399, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vt]; [vt] [at] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v] [a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' -pass 2 [other_encoding_parameters] FINAL.mkv
```

The `asetpts` and `setpts` filters reset the beginning timestamp of the trimmed videos to zero, even though in this particular instance only the end is being trimmed off.

**Note 1:** There **will** be re-encoding. I have not specified the encoding parameters. You will have to add your own as per your requirements.
**Note 2:** The `trim` and `atrim` filters' durations have to be specified in seconds.